# UITextField on focus or start editing input filed background colour change using objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am novice in objective -c ,I am facing a problem, i have a input filed, i am trying to change input field background colour when user start input on UITextField 
for input filed my code is bellow

```
 forTopUpPin = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50.90, itemTop, self.view.frame.size.width - 92, 20)];
        forTopUpPin.tag = 1;
        forTopUpPin.placeholder = @"Enter Topup PIN";
        forTopUpPin.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
        forTopUpPin.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
        forTopUpPin.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the UItexFieldDelegate protocol - specifically `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1,use delegate**

1. Set textfield Delegate to self
2. Set you viewController conforms to `UITextfieldDelegate`

   ```
   -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
   }
   -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
       textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   }
   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
     [textField resignFirstResponder];
     return true;
   }
   ```

**Option 2,use target-action**

```
    [textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldBeginEditing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

Then in the function

```
-(void)textFieldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textfield{
textfield.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks it's working . would you help you for another thing . when user done editing then input field colour will be normal or clear

Comment: See what I update,If you want more editing action,better to use `Delegate`